# In BoxCutter, how do you control distance of cutter from object?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to do a simple cut of an object in BoxCutter. How do you control the distance of the cutter from the surface of the object? (See images below.) For example, when I'm in front view and I do a simple box cut, it seems fine, but as soon as I rotate the camera, you can see that the cutter is a good distance from the surface. I want the cutter to be as close to the surface as possible.

I've tried BoxCutter Surface settings like "Local", "Nearest Edge", and "Longest Edge" but this doesn't change anything. I've also tried adjusting the Shape offset and spacing and this didn't change anything.

Sometimes the cutter starts *really* far away from the object, and then it's a pain to resize it. Is there a setting that controls how far away the cutter starts from the object?

[image]

[image]

FYI, I'm using Blender 2.92 and BoxCutter 7.17.16.

Comment: Boxcutter is a third party addon not part of Blender. However there's a good 10 minute tutorial by Josh Gambrill on using it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9DkIz5ctmg) which should cover your problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that tutorial. It doesn't explain how to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The version of BoxCutter I had had a bug. When I downloaded the latest version, the cuts now begin just above the surface where they should be.

Comment: Ah! Mine's 7.183. Glad you found it.